# how to fadein LI elements randomly? (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, fadein

Hi I've got a set of `<li>` with a hover effect, what I want is when the page loads ALL the `<li>` elements fade-in randomly.

I don't want to shuffle them...they should keep their ordering intact meaning 1,2,3,4,5.  I just want to make them appear on the page randomly and stay there.

Test page:
http://humayunrehman.com/hovertest/

Comment: When you say randomly, do you mean the timing should be random? As in "after 1-5 seconds, first element come, after 1-5 seconds second element come"?

Comment: their appearance on the page should be random...

this is the effect i was hoping to incorporate:
http://boedesign.com/demos/jsquares/

for example:

Li order (remains intact):  li-1   li-2   li-3   li-4   li-5 .... 
Appear randomly          :  3rd    1st    4th     2nd    5th

Everytime page loads they appear randomly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var v = $("#blocks > li").css('visibility', 'hidden'), cur = 0;
for(var j, x, i = v.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);
function fadeInNextLI() {
  v.eq(cur++).css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
  if(cur != v.length) setTimeout(fadeInNextLI, 50);
}
fadeInNextLI();
```

[You can view a demo with your html/images here](http://jsfiddle.net/5rkEw/).  Credit to Jordan Boesch for the sorting algorithm, the same one used in [jsquares](http://boedesign.com/demos/jsquares/).

This will hide them all, grab at random a next [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) one, fade it in, and 50ms later start the next one, creating a random-ish fadeIn effect.  Just adjust the time as needed, also pass a time into [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) if you want.  This will stop queuing effects when it's done as well.

Comment: but it displays one by one but not randomly

this is the effect i was hoping to incorporate:
http://boedesign.com/demos/jsquares/

Comment: @user366123 - Sorry I didn't get to this until now, but hopefully it's what you're after now :)

Comment: This is great, can anyone give me an idea how to fade them out randomly? and back in and so on?