# Randomize a each loop

Tags: jquery, random

I'm trying to randomize this function i made, but i've only found a random TimeOut solution. I want the order to be random not the timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function boucle() {
        $('#test img').fadeTo(1000, 0);
        $('#test img').delay(1000).each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay((i++) * 1500).fadeTo(1500, 1);
        });
    }
    boucle();
    setInterval(boucle, 15000);
});
```

I tried [this solution](http://staydecent.ca/jquery-random-each/) but this is not what i want. And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035822/how-to-fadein-li-elements-randomly-jquery) doesn't work for me.

Could someone please help me make that random loop? Thank You in advance.

**EDIT :**

Here is how i implemented the solution provided by @jack :

```
(function($) {
          $.fn.shuffle = function() {
            // credits: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
            var m = this.length, t, i;

            while (m) {
              i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

              t = this[m];
              this[m] = this[i];
              this[i] = t;
            }

            return this;
          };
        }(jQuery));

        function boucle() {
            $('#test img').fadeTo(1000, 0);
            $('#test img').shuffle().delay(1000).each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay((i++) * 1500).fadeTo(1500, 1);
            });
        }
        boucle();
        setInterval(boucle, 10000);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to randomise the order in which `each()` iterates over the elements?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Exactly !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can shuffle the result array of jQuery (using Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffling) before iterating over it using `.each()`.

Btw, you can also use this same technique to shuffle elements on the page as well.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.shuffle = function() {
    // credits: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
    var m = this.length, t, i;

    while (m) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

      t = this[m];
      this[m] = this[i];
      this[i] = t;
    }

    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function($) {
  $('div').shuffle().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: That worked ! Thank you, for learning purposes the syntaxe you used is for create a function inside of the jquery Library ? What is the advantage of doing this instead of creating the function traditionnaly like my "Boucle" function ?

Comment: @ThierryDalleau it creates a jQuery plugin that can be reused when you need it.

Comment: Ok. so this piece of code has to be in my jquery.js file ?

Comment: @ThierryDalleau No, you can put it anywhere you like

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [query-js](https://github.com/runefs/query-js) you can randomze the order like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function boucle() {
        var i = 0;
        new Query($('#test img').fadeTo(1000, 0).delay(1000))
        .orderBy(function() {
            return Math.random();
        }).iterate(function(t) {
            $(t).delay((i++) * 1500).fadeTo(1500, 1);
        });
    }
    boucle();
    setInterval(boucle, 15000);
});
```

that's using the fact that a jquery selection act as an array

Comment: Sorting an array with the results of `Math.random()` is not something I would recommend for a simple shuffle operation. In the worst case you would get O(n lg n) runtime instead of O(n).

Comment: Even worse, [it's not randomly distributed](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html)

Comment: @Bergi that is not the case with orderBy. The sort will pick a random number each time a comparison is needed. orderBy on the other hand associates a random number to each element and _reuses_ that same number. Ie orderBy when used like this will sort a list of random numbers. The distribution is thus as good as the generator of random numbers used

Comment: @Jack how do you argue that [0.0,1.[ * m is more distributed than [0.0,1.0]

Comment: @RuneFS I'm not arguing that at all, I'm saying that using the output of `Math.random()` directly as the sort compare function return value is wrong.

Comment: @Jack The random numbers are **not** used as the output of any compare function in my code. The random numbers themselves are **being** compared. Each random number is associated with one element. The random numbers are sorted and the elements are returned based on that order. So the distribution is as good as that of Math.random, however you are of course correct that a shuffling is faster

Comment: Ah, didn't realise it's a projection; that's fine in terms of distribution then.